# Return a list of values conditioned on the value in another cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet that allows a user to choose a value from a dropdown list created by Excel's data validation, and based on that value, there will be additional criteria they need to specify.

For example, let's say the user wants to use table A, and in order for the rest of my calculations to be computed, the user will be presented with two additional requirements needed to look up a value in table A e.g. gender and income. I'm envisioning that table A will be selected in say A1, and the two additional requirements will be presented in cells A2 and A3.

But, if the user wanted to use table B, they'll be presented with a different set of requirements, such as city, age, and smoker status.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to organize things, but that's what I thought of so far. I'm trying to write an IF THEN statement to say if table A, then return a named range with the specific requirements, but it's giving me an error when I try to return a range.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for cascading drop down lists

Comment: A excellent tutorial as to how to create Dependent DropDown lists is at [Debra Dagleish Contextures Web](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) site.

Comment: Thanks cybernetic.nomad and Ron Rosenfeld! That's exactly what I needed. Worked like a charm.